# Difference between two directories ignoring file type?

Tags: linux

Is there a quick way to compare two directories but ignore the file extension??
I know the command is typically:

```
diff dir1 dir2
```

But in this case apple.gif in dir1 and apple.png in dir2 two are differences.

Is there a way to get apple.gif and apple.png to be considered the same?

Comment: Do you want to compare the contents of the files, or just the filenames but ignoring the file extensions?

Comment: Also if apple.png is a valid PNG image and apple.gif is a valid GIF image, are you interested to learn if they describe the same image content?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash for loop to copy both dirs to /tmp/ without files names extensions then run diff on the copied dirs and finally delete the temporary dirs such as:

Assuming you have dir/1 and dir/2 you want to compare 1 and 2.

```
#create all dirs and subdirs
cd dir;
for i in `find . -type d `;do  mkdir /tmp/$i ;done
#copy all files without extension(remove string after last '.')
for i in `find . -type f `;do cp $i /tmp/`echo $i | rev | cut -d'.' -f 2- | rev` ;done
#run diff
diff /tmp/1 /tmp/2
#clean up ,remove created dirs
rm -rf /tmp/1 /tmp/2
```